# MySQL query, finding a row by ID and making changes to another field in the row

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a table:

[image: Table "Tickets"]

I get ticket's ID from the user. Then I need to search for the corresponding row using that ID. Then I need to change some field in the row (for instance, field 'topic'). How do I write the query to the DB?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code, have you tried googling. This is a common case of a CRUD operation, there are literally 1000's of tutorials on this all over the web.

Comment: UPDATE tickets SET topic = replace(topic, (SELECT topic FROM tickets WHERE id=2), 'Install Windows');

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
UPDATE Tickets SET topic = 'Install Windows' WHERE id=2
```

This:

```
UPDATE Tickets set topic = replace(topic, (SELECT topic FROM tickets WHERE id = 2), 'Install Windows');
```

Seems overly complicated, first you set it to update a row, then you do a select subquery on the same row which is just going around in circles.